# Custom request handler not working with qt param in apache solr (v8)

Tags: solr, solrj

I have created a custom request handler in my solrconfig.xml which is as given below:

```
<requestHandler name="/mysearch" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

      <!-- Query settings -->
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">
        title^10.0
      </str>
      <str name="pf">
        title^10.0 ph_title^5.0
      </str>
      <int name="ps">5</int>
      <str name="mm">3&lt;75% 9&lt;50%</str>
      <str name="q.alt">:</str>
      <str name="rows">10</str>
      <str name="fl">id,score</str>

      <str name="mlt.fl">state_exact</str>
      <str name="mlt.qf">
        vertical^1000.0
      </str>
      <int name="mlt.count">10</int>
      <int name="mlt.mintf">1</int>
      <int name="mlt.mindf">10</int>
      <int name="mlt.minwl">3</int>
      <bool name="mlt.boost">true</bool>
      <bool name="mlt.match.include">false</bool>

    </lst>

    <!-- append spellchecking to our list of components -->
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>mysearch_spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

But when I am calling this API:

http://10.24.7.13:8983/solr/docs/select?q=test&qt=/mysearch&fq=whitelist_cities:(Ghaziabad+OR+ALL_CITIES)&fq=-blacklist_states:(Uttar+Pradesh)&fq=whitelist_states:(Uttar+Pradesh+OR+ALL_STATES)&fq=-blacklist_pincodes:(201005+OR+BLOCK_ALL_PINCODES)&fq=whitelist_pincodes:(201005+OR+ALL_PINCODES)

the above request handler is not getting used, rather it is using the default /select handler only even though the custom is passed in qt.

However, when I hit this:

http://10.24.7.13:8983/solr/docs/mysearch?q=test&fq=whitelist_cities:(Ghaziabad+OR+ALL_CITIES)&fq=-blacklist_states:(Uttar+Pradesh)&fq=whitelist_states:(Uttar+Pradesh+OR+ALL_STATES)&fq=-blacklist_pincodes:(201005+OR+BLOCK_ALL_PINCODES)&fq=whitelist_pincodes:(201005+OR+ALL_PINCODES)

It uses the custom request handler, as expected.

Why is the first case not taking custom request handler even when qt is given?

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: "The handleSelect parameter in solrconfig.xml now defaults to false if the luceneMatchVersion is 7.0.0 or above. This causes Solr to ignore the qt parameter if it is present in a request. If you have request handlers without a leading '/', you can set handleSelect="true" or consider migrating your configuration.

The qt parameter is still used as a SolrJ special parameter that specifies the request handler (tail URL path) to use." - In general, the `qt` parameter is kind-of deprecated

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MatsLindh. However, can you pls explain -  "If you have request handlers without a leading '/', you can set handleSelect="true" or consider migrating your configuration" ?

Comment: You can set the `handleSelect` parameter in solrconfig.xml for your request handler (iirc) (if this is still supported in 8.x I don't know), but it's better to move over to use the actual path (i.e. migrate your configuration).